# How to resolve my Timer Interrupt issue

Tags: arduino-uno, timers

I am trying to work with arduino timer1 interrupts to make an led blink every bit on an 8 bit number, depending on whether its a 1 or 0. However, im trying to make a basic blinking program, and it does not seem to be working.

```
#include “TimerOne.h”
bool val=0;
void setup()
{
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    Timer1.initialize(500000); // initialize timer1, and set a 1/2 second period
    Timer1.attachInterrupt(callback); // attaches callback() as a timer overflow interrupt
}

void callback()
{
    val=1;
}

void loop()
{
    digitalWrite(13,val);
    while(!val);
    val=0;
}
```

The LED doesnt blink at all! Any help would be appreceitated!
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.

```
#include “TimerOne.h”
bool val=0;
void setup()
{
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    Timer1.initialize(500000); // initialize timer1, and set a 1/2 second period
    Timer1.attachInterrupt(callback); // attaches callback() as a timer overflow interrupt
}

void callback()
{
    val=!val;
}

void loop()
{
    digitalWrite(13,val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not surprised the LED doesn't blink - the entirety of your logic in the loop() function is so bizarre as to elicit the question:

## WTF?

Let's take a look at it line by line:

```
digitalWrite(13,val);
```

Set the LED to whatever `val` is - `val` starts as 0, so the LED is off.

```
while(!val);
```

While `val` is not anything except 0, so while val is zero, do nothing. (The interrupt would escape you from this if your `val` was `volatile`)

```
val=0;
```

Set `val` to 0.

So how can `val` be anything except 0 when you do the digitalWrite?